# Question on how to show that a set $A\times B$ is isomorphic to a coproduct of $B$ copies of $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For the following question:

Prove that the set $A\times B$ is isomorphic to a coproduct of $B$ copies of $A$. [Hint:  Think of the plane as a union of horizontal lines.]

Am i correct to interpret the hint as suggesting that I consider the map from $f:A\times B \rightarrow A\times \{\{b_i:i\in B, \wedge i\in I\}\times \{i\}\}$, defined by the function $f(a,b_i)=(a, (b_i,i))$ and $a\in A$, $b_i\in B$ for $i\in I$.  Here $(b_i,i)$ denotes I am decomposing $B$ into singleton sets $\{(b_i,i)\}$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The hint is that the elements of $B$ themselves can be taken as the "index" elements in the coproduct. Just prove that $A\times B$ satisfies the universal property for the coproduct of $B$-many copies of $A$.

Comment: @blargoner the text i am using has not introduce the concept of "universal property" at the place where this exercise is introduced.

Comment: Are you [sure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580342/how-to-generalize-the-definition-of-a-coproduct-for-an-indexed-family-of-sets)?

Comment: @blargoner oh ok, if that is what you mean by universal property.  The author did not call it that.  There are other similarly looking commutative diagrams in the same and later sections.  Like the notion of choice function, he doesn't really go into details about them besides telling the reader such and such are choice functions without elaborating further about why they are called "choice" function even when the reader will likely ask such question when they are introduce at two different contexts.

Comment: @blargoner can I ask about showing a mathematical object 1 satisfies the universal mapping property of mathematical object 2, how does that help with showing isomorphism between mathematical object 1 and mathematical object 2.  In the book i am using, there is a theorem which states that the coproduct/product of two objects is unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: That's precisely the theorem that helps you here. If both objects satisfy the UMP of a coproduct, they must be isomorphic by the theorem.

Comment: @blargoner I think it might be better I make a separate post about this issue. I don't want to get in trouble for having lengthy discussion in the comments section.  I really appreciate you pointing out to me something I need to understand further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on my comments: the hint is that the elements of $B$ in $A\times B$ themselves can be taken as the "index" elements for the coproduct of $B$-many copies of $A$, and we can prove that $A\times B$ satisfies the universal property for the coproduct.

To see this, for each $b\in B$ define $A_b=A$ and define the injection $i_b:A_b\to A\times B$ by $i_b(a)=(a,b)$. Now given any set $C$ and functions $q_b:A_b\to C$ for all $b\in B$, we can define a function $q:A\times B\to C$ by
$$q(a,b)=q_b(a)$$
It is easy to see that $q\circ i_b=q_b$ for all $b\in B$, and $q$ is unique satisfying this property (that is, if $q':A\times B\to C$ satisfies $q'\circ i_b=q_b$ for all $b\in B$, then $q'=q$). This shows that the pair $(A\times B,(i_b)_{b\in B})$ satisfies the universal property for the coproduct of $B$-many copies of $A$. By uniqueness of the coproduct it is isomorphic to any other "implementation"; more precisely, for any coproduct $(\coprod_{b\in B}A_b,(j_b)_{b\in B})$, there is a unique isomorphism $F:A\times B\to\coprod_{b\in B}A_b$ with $F\circ i_b=j_b$ for all $b\in B$.